# Laravel, Update Multiple rows Arrays

Tags: html, arrays, laravel, loops, rows

I' am trying to update data multiple rows using array.
Maybe the way I did it still had a few mistakes, so this is the problem.

I have one data stored in the database, I convert the data into an array so that you can better understand it.

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "I"
  1 => "like"
  2 => "your"
  3 => "Mom"
]
```

when i try to update the data *example

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "I"
  1 => "like"
  2 => "your"
  3 => "dad"
]
```

The result is different from my expectations. here the result:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "dad"
  1 => "dad"
  2 => "dad"
  3 => "dad"
]
```

here my controller

```
public function updateTestCaseUser(Request $id)
    {
        $input = $id->all();

        $x = TestCase::find($id["id"]);
        $x->test_scenario = $input["test_scenario"];
        $x->post_condition = $input["post_condition"];
        $x->pre_condition = $input["pre_condition"];
        $x->expected_result = $input["expected_result"];
        // $x->steps = $input["steps"];
        $x->actual_result = $input["actual_result"];
        $x->status = $input["status"];
        $x->save();

        // Ignore these all ^

        $hitung = $id->steps;
        $hitung2 = count($hitung);

            for ($i=0; $i < $hitung2; $i++) {

                $y = Steps::find($id["id"]);
                $y->steps = $id->steps[$i]; // I am really sure the problem is at here

                $y->save();
            }

        return redirect("/testing/user/document")->with('Alert-succes', 'Succesfull');
    }
```

Ignore the top of $hitung. When I use dd() on $hitung. the result is same as I expected. be like

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "I"
  1 => "like"
  2 => "your"
  3 => "dad"
]
```

My migration of table steps

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('steps', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('id_steps')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('id_steps')->references('id')->on('test_cases')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('id_document');
            $table->integer('id_test_case');
            $table->text('steps');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: where in the code are you trying to update these arrays ?

Comment: look up the controller, look at $hitung to for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really making a guess here but... maybe..

```
$y->steps[$i] = $id->steps[$i];
```

---

### Edit

In your migration you need.

```
$table->json('steps');
```

and in your model add

```
protected $casts = [
    'steps' => 'array',
];
```

then you can write

```
$y->steps = $id->steps
```

without the loop

Comment: it doens't work , the message error was apper be like. Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Steps::$steps has no effect

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure why are you looping the $steps. Can't you just use $y->steps = $id->steps

Comment: I've been tried that way, but its still apper a error message. Array to string conversion (SQL:  
I am try use implode, but the result is making all my input data into one lines *examp Ilkeyoudad

Comment: Done, just look up at my question

Comment: see edit. and check https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Comment: What? I use $cast on my model, it makes things worse.

Comment: what is happening

Comment: How does it look in the database? Are they saved properly?

Comment: I'll do it later, I'm busy with another job, besides that it seems like it's very promising